# Qt5 MediaPlayer setMedia use http in macos

Tags: macos, qt5

i want to play a mp3 using a http url,so i found Qt5 MediaPlayer. But i get a issue,when i set `player->setMedia(QUrl('http://xxx'));`.

```
2016-01-02 01:46:02.544 myPlayer[82519:5587404] App Transport Security     has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http), but i don't know how to add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `info.plist` file for your application. Then at your `.pro` file add this:

```
QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = Info.plist
```

From Qt documentation:

> QMAKE_INFO_PLIST
>
> Specifies the name of the property list file, .plist, you would like
>   to include in your OS X and iOS application bundle.
>
> In the .plist file, you can define some variables, e.g., @EXECUTABLE@,
>   which qmake will replace with the actual executable name. Other
>   variables include @ICON@, @TYPEINFO@, @LIBRARY@, and @SHORT_VERSION@.